# How to apply border-radius css property on ion-menu in ionic 4?

Tags: css, angular7, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 Angular app , in the app i'm using ion-menu to show menu items. how to apply border-top-right-radius and border-bottom-right-radius css properties on ion-menu ? Below image shows what exactly i want. [Here is ion-menu documentation link.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu)

[image: ion-menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo think this achieves what you want:

global.scss

```
ion-menu{
    --ion-toolbar-background: grey;
    ion-list{
         border: 2px solid grey !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px !important;
    background: grey !important;


    }
    ion-item{
        --background: grey !important;
        --color: #fff;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are great, every time saved my whole day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
.ion-item-border {
 border-radius: 20px !important;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-top: 5px; 
}
```